# Return HTTP response with status code 202 in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-codes

How can I return HTTP response with status code 202?

I couldn't find any reference for it in Spring Boot documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return HTTPStatus [ACCEPTED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#ACCEPTED), e.g:

```
 return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

> 202 Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this (I am using kotlin) :

```
return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(OrderResponse().order(order))
```

OR Easy way is:

```
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(OrderResponse().order(order))
```

ResponseEntity.accepted returns 202
ResponseEntity.created returns 201
and so on

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No Article found with this Article Number.")
public class NoArticleFoundException extends RuntimeException{

    private static final long serialVersionUID =3935230281455340039L;
}
```

Instead of writing NOT_FOUND , you can write ACCEPTED and give some text in reason field. And then call this method from another class or when ever required. (extends part is not required)